# Asterisk MeetMe conference splitting

Tags: sip, asterisk, conference

How to move 2 of 3 users in the MeetMe conference to the newly created MeetMe conference?
I'm not very familiar with Asterisk, will be great if some one can provide dialplan example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need determine which users you want move, for example you need know channels names.

After that you can use

```
ChannelRedirect(${CHANNELNAME},conference_context,${CONFNO},1)
```

Which will move user to extension ${CONFNO} in conference_context. In that context you need have something like

```
[conference_context]
exten => _X.,1,Meetme(${EXTEN},d)
```

Unfortanly no easy way select CHANNELNAME via dialplan. It will require some very complex context which require guru level to create. You can't move user by it number in conference(becuase no numbers).